# NSOperationQueue not limiting concurrent operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

```
NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    myQueue.MaxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;

    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        NSLog(@"started");
        [self aVeryLongOperation];
    }];
```

The number of concurrent operations is limited to one, but nontheless they all start. Say three operations were added, and the output in the console is as follows:

```
2014-09-09 17:51:02.705 Sample App [7356:7e03] started
2014-09-09 17:51:03.840 Sample App [7356:7e03] started
2014-09-09 17:51:04.495 Sample App [7356:7e03] started
```

How do I actually limit the number of concurrent operations to exactly one?

Comment: Add a log statement after the call to `aVeryLongOperation` - `NSLog(@"ended");`. What's the output?

Comment: Taking the code as written, it would seem that you are creating three NSOperationQueues. Concurrent operation limits are per queue.

Comment: Yep, I was indeed creating three NSOperationQueues. So I changed that, placing the 'myQueue' as a property, but unfortunately the console log is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The thing was that inside the function `aVeryLongOperation` a background thread, on which all the work was done, was spawned. So that function returned right after spawning that thread, and the next task was taken from the queue to be executed.